# How to get coloured pixel from hex colour code in python?

Tags: python

This is my code for converting text into color pixel but it prints only dot of a particular color.

```
from colored import fg, bg, attr
d={}
d["a"]="#800000"
d["b"]="#c0c0c0"
d["c"]="#ffff00" 
d["d"]="#000080"
d["e"]="#ffffff"
d["f"]="#ff00ff"
d["g"]="#808080"
d["h"]="#008080"
d["i"]="#005f00"
d["j"]="#00afff"
d["k"]="#00ffff"
d["l"]="#5f0000" 
d["m"]="#5f5f5f"
d["n"]="#5f5fd7"
d["o"]="#5f8700"
d["p"]="#5fff5f"
d["q"]="#870087"
d["r"]="#875faf"
d["s"]="#878787"
d["t"]="#af00af"
d["u"]="#af5f87"
d["v"]="#afff00"
d["w"]="#d75fff"
d["x"]="#d787d7"
d["y"]="#d7afff"
d["z"]="#ffd700"
for key in d:
    color = fg(d[key])
    res = attr('reset')
    print (color + "." + res)
```

This above program print dots of particular color. I want to print a `pixel` of a particular color.

Comment: How do you expect your output to be is it rgb format ?

Comment: In coloured pixel format?@ Chetan Vasudevan

Comment: My output in colored dot format.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colored ...  its probably worth noting it appears that you are using the "colored" package ... windows doesnt usually work very well with ansii escape sequences in my experience (however here is my output on a tty terminal https://i.imgur.com/AHiQUWf.png)

Comment: why You just don't use some charater which looks like pixel for ex this █, the only problem probably will be unicode support.